# creating a bar with core animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-animation

So I am trying to create an animated bar graph using apple core animation. The bar is just basically a rectangular figure, which have a value of 0-100%. When it first appears I wanted it to show an animation going from 0 to x %. How can I draw a rectangular form like this?

UPDATE:
Most probably I will have a bar as an image, so I need to animate this image to a certain height...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
- (UIImageView*)createNewBarWithValue:(float)percent atLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
    UIImageView *newBar = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 50, 200)] autorelease];
    newBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];

    CABasicAnimation *scaleToValue = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"];
    scaleToValue.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percent];
    scaleToValue.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    scaleToValue.duration = 1.0f;
    scaleToValue.delegate = self;

    newBar.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);

    [newBar.layer addAnimation:scaleToValue forKey:@"scaleUp"];
    CGAffineTransform scaleTo = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 1.0f, percent );
    newBar.transform = scaleTo;

    return newBar;
}
```

Comment: this actually does the job, however what if I want to add a bouncy effect when it finishes to the top?

Comment: Hello could you help us to know how are you calling this method. Is this is in the view or ViewController. And what is percentage  (0-100/0-1) and point are corresponding to VC or view. thanks

Comment: It has been a while, but I believe everything in this snippet is relative to the view controller. Called from the view controller, etc., then added to the view controller's view.

Comment: Thanks, but    UIImageView *img = [self createNewBarWithValue:2 atLocation:CGPointMake(160, 230)];
[self.view addSubview:img]; trying this but it always draw form different position.

Comment: Hm. If it's drawing in an unexpected position, I would suggest trying to play with the anchor point value in the above function. (newBar.layer.anchorPoint). That being said, the comments section is not really the place for extended personal help; if you need more, please PM me. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If your requirements are really that simple, you could create a view, set its background color and adjust (or animate) its frame.width (or height) as needed.

Of course there are more elaborate ways to do this, but no need to over-engineer for a simple problem.

Comment: the issue is that I have an image of the bar...so it's not just a view

Comment: The UIImageView (which is a UIView descendent) can be animated as picciano said.

Comment: so in that case I would need to have multiple images or do I just need an initial image and final image and then I can somehow animate just using these two images?

Comment: You'd use just one image and it would be scaled and stretched, depending on your UIImageView's `contentMode`. You should also check out UIImage's `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` if you have the image to be stretched intelligently, e.g. so that a source image with bevelled corners doesn't change the size of the bevel when the whole image changes.